# Using grep on an output of previous operations

Tags: bash, unix, grep, wc

can I search a word by using grep on an output (and not a file like in it's origin syntax). 
for example:

```
echo "Hello World"|grep <word_to_search>
```

Otherwise how do I search something in an output ?

**Addition:** 
a little complication to this question. How do I tell grep to find something in a particular part of a word, which had a concrete structure ? 
For example, I want to find all the email addresses with particular domain, but the domain must be after "@" and before ".com", how should I do it? 
Should I use cut, so I would be left only with the domain or can I say to grep that I want to search something from a form: @., for example:

```
echo "dani123@gmail.com"|grep "*"@"$domain"."*"
```

Is this the correct way to do it?

Another way, that could help is doing the same with "wc":

```
echo "dani123@gmail.com"|grep "*"@"$domain"."*"
```

Or must I use "cut" in this purpose ?

Comment: That's *exactly* how you do it. Perhaps you should have tried :-)

Comment: Yep, and just found it on google. Perhaps :)

Comment: Your edit asks a completely different question, and still reveals very little studying of manuals. You are looking for a regular expression which matches the pattern you want to extract.  There are many examples here on how to match an email address with a regex, none of which look remotely like your speculation.